# How to ignore "Error: <rect> attribute height: A negative value is not valid. ("-64")" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, logging

Not familiar with JS and I'm trying to ignore this error so that it does not log it in the console since we are expecting a negative value.

Code that throws the error:

```js
tnBar.setAttribute("height", tnValue.toString()) // this line throws the error
fnBar.setAttribute("height", fnValue.toString()) 
tpBar.setAttribute("height", tpValue.toString())
fpBar.setAttribute("height", fpValue.toString())
```

I tried wrapping the entire method in a try catch as well as wrapping the code above:

```js
try {
    tnBar.setAttribute("height", tnValue.toString() // this line throws the error
    fnBar.setAttribute("height", fnValue.toString()) 
    tpBar.setAttribute("height", tpValue.toString())
    fpBar.setAttribute("height", fpValue.toString())
} catch(err){
    // do nothing
}
```

Comment: The first line seems to be missing a parenthesis `)` in the end. Also there's a spare ` character in the end of the first block. Are you sure you are posting the correct code?

Comment: Copy and paste error. Small errors aside, the error still gets logged in the console

Comment: Does `console.clear()` accomplish what you're looking for?